# How to use module source from NPM in my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I install a module via npm, what is the proper way to use the code in my website? I mean simply making `node_modules` static seems ridiculous, but I can't figure out how to easily create a static folder with the few pieces of JS I want to use in it.

Of course there are symbolic links and a lot of hacks I can think of off the top of my head, but I was just curious if there is a known workflow/way to solve this problem that I simply haven't read about yet.

Comment: You'll need a bundler like browserify, webpack or rollup. I'd recommend browserify for your first project as it's a little simpler to get started.

Comment: Look at browserify or webpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) are the tools usually chosen to bundle up modules managed through npm for deployment to be used client side.

Answer (score 1):

You want [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)

> webpack supports pre-processing files via loaders. This allows you to
>   bundle any static resource not only javascript. You can easily write
>   your own loaders running in node.js.